# Boot Partition doesn't have the correct storage space

Tags: macos, mac, storage

So my SSD has 500 GB of storage I have only one Partition (the Macintosh HD Partition) but it only has ~100 GB storage space.

[image: MY Drive in Disk Utility]

Is there any way I can get my total ~500 GB of storage on my partition?

here is what shows up in terminal (command diskutil list)

[image]

Comment: @klanomath I now added a picture of diskutil list but I can't execute the other command. It is asking me for a password even though I don't have one. Just pressing enter doesn't work btw.

Comment: BTW A command prepended with `sudo ` (e.g `sudo gpt -r show disk0`) asks for your admin password (if you are logged in as an admin). After entering this password the command will be executed. ;-) (`gpt -r show disk0` shows the partition table of disk0)

Comment: @klanomath Well I don't have an admin password, at least not that I know. Well anyway thank you for your help :)

Comment: After seeing the "Microsoft Reserved partition" it was rather obvious what had happened previously...and the output of the gpt command wasn't really required.

Comment: @klanomath Now that you mention it I had windows 10 installed which actually wasn't possible on my mac. I managed to do it by screwing around with the bootcamp files. I totally forgot that I had installed windows once. I guess I didn't correctly uninstall it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably had some dual boot config previously and removed the main Windows partition(s). You didn't expand the APFS container disk0s2 afterwards.

A small blocking disk0s3 is a left-over though (right "after" disk0s2). This small partition has to be removed before you can expand your APFS container.

1. Erase the Microsoft Reserved partition:

   ```
   diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" %noformat% /dev/disk0s3
   ```
2. Expand the APFS container:

   ```
   diskutil apfs resizeContainer /dev/disk0s2 0
   ```